# How to have a logo appear in sticky menu on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio

I have a sticky sub-menu. When i scroll to a section on the page, this menu sticks to the top. However, I would like the logo to appear on scroll and be hidden when the sticky menu is not at the top.How would I accomplish that? Here is an example of what i am trying to do (you need to scroll part way down the page to see the sticky menu) - https://www.vidyard.com/platform/viewedit/

The logo and the 'get a demo' button are what i am trying to achieve.

```js
        var menu = document.querySelector('.menu-t')
        var menuPosition = menu.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
            if (window.pageYOffset >= menuPosition) {
                menu.style.position = 'fixed';
                menu.style.top = '0px';
            } else {
                menu.style.position = 'static';
                menu.style.top = '';
            }
        });
```

```css
.page-section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-section.page-section-center {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}


.menu-t {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-bottom: 1px #eee dotted;
}
.menu-t li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.menu-t a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #32404E !important;
  -webkit-transition: color ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: color ease 0.3s;
  transition: color ease 0.3s;
}
.menu-t a:hover {
  color: #2db2e9 !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="page-section">
  <br/>
  <br/>
    <br/>
  <br/>
  </section>
<section class="page-section page-section-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <ul class="menu-t">
      <li>ITEM</li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="text-thick">What Is</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#" class="text-thick">How</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="text-thick">You're In Good Company</a>
        </li>
      <li>ITEM</li>
    </ul>
</section>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this.

Create an img element within li element with display hidden at the the start and hide/show it on scroll.

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu-t')
        var menuPosition = menu.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
            if (window.pageYOffset >= menuPosition) {
                menu.style.position = 'fixed';
                menu.style.top = '0px';
                menu.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.display = "block";
                
            } else {
                menu.style.position = 'static';
                menu.style.top = '';
                menu.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.style.display = "none";
            }
        });
```

```css
.page-section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-section.page-section-center {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}


.menu-t {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-bottom: 1px #eee dotted;
}
.menu-t li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.menu-t a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #32404E !important;
  -webkit-transition: color ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: color ease 0.3s;
  transition: color ease 0.3s;
}
.menu-t a:hover {
  color: #2db2e9 !important;
}

.menu-t li img{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="page-section">
  <br/>
  <br/>
    <br/>
  <br/>
  </section>
<section class="page-section page-section-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <ul class="menu-t">
      
         <li>
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRJfyp7Gqe9jDGcVUgJIq0iTOOyzv6MkOthkXkAOzvqiiBPHceh"/>
        </li>
        <li>ITEM</li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="text-thick">What Is</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#" class="text-thick">How</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="text-thick">You're In Good Company</a>
        </li>
      <li>ITEM</li>
    </ul>
</section>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
```

Comment: This works - except for on page load it loads the image. Then as you start to scroll it hides it, and then when you reach the sticky menu, it appears again. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @becca did you add this css .menu-t li img{ display: none;} , it should hide the image by default on page load

Comment: @becca NP :) glad to help

Answer (score 0):

The logo in your example is there in the navbar the whole time. They use `visibility: hidden;` to begin, and then `visibility: visible;` when the scrollbar sticks to the top.